# Custom Script to Capitalize each word on a Google Sheet

Tags: scripting, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with multiple columns and rows and multiple contributors. 
I need a script capable of keeping each first word capitalized in the entire sheet.
Example
Mike Jordan

and if it finds capitalized words "MIKE JORDAN" to correct it to "Mike Jordan" automatically.

Comment: Would be better to pull the data into Excel, execute a piece of code there and then write it back to the google spreadsheet. Writing JavaScript to modify the web elements and then hitting save seems like a hazzle to me. The function `Proper()` is your friend here, it does exactly what you want. (http://www.howtogeek.com/164598/how-to-quickly-and-easily-change-case-in-excel-2013-using-a-function/)

Comment: You don't need to pull it into excel - that same function is also in google sheets

Answer (score 0):

You can use the proper() function.

```
=PROPER(A:A)
```

If you want to run the whole column try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER(A:A))
```